# How can I call sp_executesql stored procedure in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

How can I call sp_executesql stored procedure in entity framework? 
I need to dynamically execute formulas stored in SQL Server table column using Select Statement. I tried ENTITY SQL but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand` (requires EF 4).

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_calculatesalary(@EmployeeId as int)  
begin
declare @dynsql varchar(500)=' Salary,Username from employee where EmployeeId=@empID'    
exec sp_executesql @dynsql,'@empID int',@empID=@EmployeeID
SELECT 1 as salary,2 as username
end
```

it solves stored procedures mapping problem